# How to implement AutoFill functionality in Xamarin Forms for iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have to implement autofill service for iOS in Xamarin forms, Is there any sample code ? How we can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms.AutoSuggestBox](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms.AutoSuggestBox/) from nuget .

### Usage

#### xaml

```
<AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" WidthRequest="200"
                TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
                QuerySubmitted="AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
                SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen"/>
```

#### Code Behind

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Only get results when it was a user typing, 
    // otherwise assume the value got filled in by TextMemberPath 
    // or the handler for SuggestionChosen.
    if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
    {
        //Set the ItemsSource to be your filtered dataset
        //sender.ItemsSource = dataset;
    }
}


private void AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    // Set sender.Text. You can use args.SelectedItem to build your text string.
}


private void AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
    {
        // User selected an item from the suggestion list, take an action on it here.
    }
    else
    {
        // User hit Enter from the search box. Use args.QueryText to determine what to do.
    }
}
```

For more details you can check https://github.com/dotMorten/XamarinFormsControls/tree/master/AutoSuggestBox